# Add a blinking effect to single character of array

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to achieve blinking effect to a single character of an array.

For example, if "text" get load inside paragraph `<p>` tag or container then first character of text should blink and when user types the blinking character in input area blinking effect must move to blink on next character.

I need assistance in solving this problem. Any instructions or help will be so grateful.

Here what I've tried so far:

```js
let displayElem = document.getElementById("me");
const inputElem = document.getElementById("input");
const text = "Hey It's bad day, not a bad life,you'll be okay...!"

text.split('').forEach(char => {
  const chrspan = document.createElement('span')
  chrspan.innerText = char;
  displayElem.appendChild(chrspan);
});


inputElem.addEventListener('input', () => {
  var vl = document.getElementById("input").value;
  const arrayq = displayElem.querySelectorAll('span')
  const arrayv = inputElem.value
  let correct = true;

  arrayq.forEach((chSpan, index) => {
    const char = arrayv[index];

    if (char == null) {
      correct = false;
    } else if (char === chSpan.innerText) {
      chSpan.classList.add('blink-bg')
    } else {
      chSpan.classList.remove('blink-bg')
      correct = false
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.blink-bg {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  animation: blinkingBackground 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes blinkingBackground {
  from { background-color: #f1ebeb; }
  to { background-color: #080808; }
}
```

```html
<p id="me"></p>
<input id="input" type="input" />
```

```js
let displayElem = document.getElementById("me");
const inputElem = document.getElementById("input");
const text = "Hey It's bad day, not a bad life,you'll be okay...!"

text.split('').forEach(char => {
  const chrspan = document.createElement('span')
  chrspan.innerText = char;
  displayElem.appendChild(chrspan);
});

inputElem.addEventListener('input', () => {
  var vl = document.getElementById("input").value;
  const arrayq = displayElem.querySelectorAll('span')
  const arrayv = inputElem.value
  let correct = true;

  arrayq.forEach((chSpan, index) => {
    const char = arrayv[index];

    if (char == null) {
      correct = false;
    } else if (char === chSpan.innerText) {
      chSpan.classList.add('blink-bg')
      // document.getElementById("p_id").innerHTML = chSpan.innerText;
    } else {
      chSpan.classList.remove('blink-bg')
      correct = false
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Are you requiring that when the second character is typed the first character stops having the blinking effect?

Comment: thanks for your comment and Yes. it must stop in previews character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a good starting point for you. I changed a couple things,
I made a helper function `$` to grab items from the dom as a personal prefrence.

I created an array of all the spans on the document, making it easier to keep track of which element has the blinking class. I created a helper function to grab what the activeText is from the `txtArr` instead of checking the text content. This way I can avoid using the rendered screen as a storage area for information, and instead have the screen mirror what is happening in my js.

On input I check the last character entered, and if it is the character that is blinking, I increment increment which span is blinking.

This is meant to be a simple demo of how to accomplish this task, you may want to have different functionality, but hopefully this helps as a starting point!

```js
const $ = str => [...document.querySelectorAll(str)];
let displayElem = $("#me")[0];
const inputElem = $("#input")[0];
const text = "Hey! It's a bad day, not a bad life, you'll be okay...!"
const txtArr = [...text];
const txtSpans = txtArr.map(char => {
  const span = document.createElement("span");
  span.innerText = char;
  return span;
});
let activeIndex = -1;
const activeText = () => txtArr[activeIndex];

function renderSpans() {
  displayElem.innerHtml = "";
  txtSpans.forEach(span => displayElem.appendChild(span));
};

function updateActive() {
  const firstRun = activeIndex == -1;
  if (!firstRun) 
    txtSpans[activeIndex].classList.remove("blink-bg");
  activeIndex++;
  if (activeIndex == txtSpans.length) return;
  txtSpans[activeIndex].classList.add("blink-bg");
}
updateActive();
renderSpans();

inputElem.addEventListener('input', e => {
  const val = e.target.value;
  if (val == "") return;
  const lastChar = val[val.length - 1];
  if (lastChar == activeText()) updateActive();
})
```

```css
.blink-bg {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  animation: blinkingBackground 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes blinkingBackground {
  from { background-color: #f1ebeb; }
  to { background-color: #080808; }
}
```

```html
<p id="me"></p>
<input id="input" type="input" />
```

Comment: I've noticed that pressing backspace when making a mistake, if the last char in a string is the target char, it will increment (as told), which may not be intended. Also spaces don't blink as intended.